# center of mass of rotating rod system

Tags: forces, centre-of-gravity

I have a system with a rot connected to a motor and I need to determine the center of mass to calculate the moment caused by gravitation.

To illustrate:

[image]

I am uncertain about how to do this, is it a poor assumption to only consider the length along the rod? such that I get the length from the rod end (where the motor is attached) to the center of mass to be:

$L_{cm} = \frac{L_{1,y} \cdot m_1 + L_{2,y} \cdot m_2 + L_{3,y}  \cdot m_3}{m_1+m_2+m_3}$

Where $L_{i,y}$ is the length from the end to i'th mass along the rod (y direction).

Can I do this or do I need to consider the direct lengths? If this is the case how can I determine the gravitation Moment if the center of mass is not located at the system (meaning that if I use direct length the center of mass might be located beside the rod)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment experienced by the drives will be the sum of the three moments. Yes, you have to calculate to the centre of each mass, not the distance along the rod.

[image]

Let $\alpha$ be the angle of each radius from the horizontal. The total moment can then be calculated by,

$$ M = L_1m_1cos\alpha_1 + L_2m_2cos\alpha_2 + L_3m_3cos\alpha_3$$

Comment: Okay I though I could simplify the gravitation to one point. But Thanks!

Comment: You can simplify to one point. I'll have to think for a while!